# PyCharm pytest and environment variables not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I', using Pycharm in Ubuntu using python 3.7 and 3.8, and I'm facing two problems:

1. I'm using pytest, when I try to run it using run 'pytest  for.. it doesn't show the test window and prints nothing, just "Process finished with exit code 0"

If I run the test with pytest filename.py it works just fine.

What could be missing? From File -> Settings -> Tools -> Python Integrated Tools -> Default test runner is already set to pytest

[image]

2. I'm setting environment variables as shown bellow, but when trying to import it, it gets None

```
    import os

print(os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

First problem - you have a "pure Python" run configuration for `api_test.py` so when you try to run this file PyCharm reuses the configuration instead of creating a new one.

[image]

To resolve this issue either use **Run | Run ...** menu and select "pytest" there - PyCharm will create a new "test" run configuration.

Or remove `api_test` configuration from **Run | Edit Configurations ...** so there will be nothing no re-use for PyCharm.

The corresponding ticket in PyCharm's bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-30052 Please vote for it.

---

Second problem - this is the right direction but a wrong menu. You are setting the environment  variable for PyCharm built-in Python Console while you need to set it for a specific run configuration.

**Run | Edit Configurations ...** -> select the configuration used to run a script which checks the environment variable and define it there.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can install the plugin
[pytest-env](https://github.com/MobileDynasty/pytest-env)

(this package was last updated 4 years ago, but still gets the job done - I am using python 3.8.5 and pipenv 2020.8.13 and it works well).

and then add to your **pytet.ini** file  the environment variables you would like to set:

```
[pytest]
addopts = -s -v

env =
    SECRET_KEY = 12345
```

BTW, This plugin is intended to env vars and I thing using it with secret keys is a bit of abuse, but it will get the job done.